# Excel vba do not display zeros at the end

Tags: excel, vba

How to display zeros at the end of doubles?

> A1 = 278,50

```
Sub test()
Dim f As Double
f = Range("A1").Value
MsgBox f

End Sub
```

Msgbox return 278,5 but i need 278,50 
There are ways except & "00" to show zeros at the end of numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Format` function to convert your number to a string of your desired format:

```
MsgBox Format(f, "0.00")
```

If you want to keep the same number format that the cell has, then you can do this:

```
MsgBox Format(f, Range("A1").NumberFormat)
```

Alternatively, display the `Text` shown in the cell, instead of its value:

```
MsgBox Range("A1").Text
```

But beware: `.Text` will display `###` if the cell happens to be too narrow to display its contents!

Testing all three at once:

```
MsgBox Format(f, "0.00") & vbCrLf _
    & Format(f, Range("A1").NumberFormat) & vbCrLf _
    & Range("A1").Text
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: MsgBox Range("A1").Text return without zero

Comment: Please show us a screenshot of cell A1, and let us know what its number format is, else we can't help.